# How to get all data from Category in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I am new in Codeigniter, Please help me.

My Codeigniter url is - `http://localhost/framework/CodeIgniter/index.php/restaurant/patna/`

I want to get all data.

I set the route -

```
$route['restaurant(:any)'] = "Restaurant/getRestaurantByCity/$1";
```

And my function in Controller is

here i want the category id where pass the cat_id in below function for get all the data of that category

```
public function getRestaurantByCity()
{
   $rst_list = $this->Restaurant_model->get_restaurant_by_city();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

**controller**

```
$this->data['RestaurantByCity'] =  $this->Restaurant_model->getRestaurantByCity();
    echo "<pre>"; print_R($this->data['RestaurantByCity']);
```

**model**

```
 public function getRestaurantByCity($ids){
    $sql ="select * from categoriestableName where categories_id in($ids) order by categories_id asc";
    $rs = $this->db->query($sql);
    foreach($rs->result() as $record ){
        $result[] = $record;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Restaurant extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getRestaurantByCity($id)
    {
        $this->load->model('Restaurant_model');
        $rst_list = $this->Restaurant_model->get_restaurant_by_city($id);
    }
}
```